# Commit a file to a forked repository on github

Tags: github

I am totally new on github. How do I commit a new file to a forked repository? I am looking on google but the information I have found do not help at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clone that fork the same way you would clone a regular repository.

Then you can simply commit the file to the repository.

```sh
git clone git@github.com:username/repo.git
cd repo
touch some_file
git commit -am "message"
git push origin master
```

If you want your changes to go the original repository you will have to create a pull request from your repository to the original repository. (a link should be displayed for a while on your repositorie's page after you've pushed something)